# How to get the name of the file that was just written by a Spark Job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have this simple Hadoop application in Scala. I'm repartitioning and writing to 2 files. I however, need to know the file name that was just written.

```
package com.scala.sparkscalaplayground
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerTaskEnd}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

object SimpleSparkHadoopApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Spark Hadoop")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val data = Seq(("John", 25), ("Alice", 30), ("Bob", 22))
    val columns = Seq("Name", "Age")
    var df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data).toDF(columns: _*)
    df = df.repartition(2)
    sparkSession.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener {
      override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd): Unit = {
        val records = taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten
        val bytes = taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.bytesWritten
        val fileName = "" // Is there a way I can get this filename?
        print(s"${bytes} bytes were written on ${records} records in file ${fileName}")
      }
    })
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv("output/")
  }
}
```

How can I do that?

I have seen suggestions from people about reading the output directory and re-reading the files but I'm dealing with Petabytes of data and re-reading is not an option.

What can I do to get those filenames?

Additionally, can I pass some custom parameters from where I do `df.write` and get it in the listener?

Any insights will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe names are assigned to the files during commit, i.e. when _all tasks_ have completed and the files are copied from staging to final location, not on each task's end.